# What is the result of unpacking with * or **?

Tags: python

What is the result of unpacking? I thought the unpacking result is a first class citizen that I can use as an object.

```
>>> print(*range(5))
0 1 2 3 4
```

However, apparently it cannot be evaluated to be an object and I cannot get its type. So, I wonder what is the unpacking operation generating?

```
>>> *range(5)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here

>>> type(*range(5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments

>>> *values, = 1,2,3

>>> values
[1, 2, 3]
>>> *values
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: Why do you assume there is a result? Syntax does not necessarily have to be an expression that can be evaluated in all contexts.

Comment: *"I thought the unpacking result is a first class citizen that I can use as an object."* Why did you think this? Is there a language reference which says so?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) and [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: @timgeb, I think it is what I have not understood yet. "Syntax does not necessarily have to be an expression". Currently I think "syntax is to be evaluated to generate a result" and I am assuming "result is an object".

Comment: @timgeb, For ```print(*range(5))```, it generates ```0,1,2,3,4```, so I thought at somewhere ```*range(5)``` has been ```evaluated``` to generate those integer '0' or '1', etc. Appreciate if you could explain how Python interpreter generates those integers from ```*``` syntax.

Comment: @mon: nice question. For me, the strangest thing is that `x = *range(5),` will evaluate to a tuple, but `x = *range(5)` is a SyntaxError. Somewhere in Python Developer's Guide should be clear answer to your question.

Comment: Unpacking **is** the act of taking a collection and using its element as *different function arguments*. This means that it exists only in the context of a function call.
Assignment unpacking is a similar thing that uses the same syntax in a different context `start,*middle,end = range(5)` this does some form of pattern matching to assign `0` to `start`, `[1,2,3]` to `middle` and `4` to `end`.

Comment: @Qiu, it's not strange at all. Trailing coma creates tuple, so you just unpacking range into a tuple. `x = *range(5),` is the same as `x = tuple(range(5))`

Comment: `*range(5)` isn't a thing, but `func(*<iterable>)` is. This is maybe as succinctly as it can be put. The `*` is part of the function call syntax, not the other way around. (And for completeness, certain other constructs supports it as well, like `[*<iterable>]`.)

Comment: @mon There are many sequences of characters that are correct syntax but do not return a result, for example `def foo(): pass`. You cannot put it on the right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: There is probably a better duplicate to use. Unpacking is quite different from a `*` parameter in a function definition, syntactic similarities aside.